# Got an Snowflake Error Code : 300010:144855164 when executing a SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, runtime-error

I have a giant SQL with multiple CTE's in it. The query runs for 3 hours and it errors out with the error message as : SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300010:144855164; incident 4421801.

```
Insert into Tb1(
Col1 ,
Col2
Col3 ...
)
with CTE_1 as (...),
CTE_2 as (...),
CTE_3 as (...),
CTE_4 as (...),
CTE_4 as (...)
select a.col1,
b.col2,
c.col3...
from 
CTE_1 a left join 
CTE_2 b on a.col3=b.col3 
left join CTE_3 on a.col3=c.col3 ....
```

I tried to limit the CTE queries  with small subset of data and it works fine and data gets inserted as expected. Any suggestions as how to I can troubleshoot this further ?

I have a large dataset running into billions of records and have a few aggregate functions with CTE's. I am using the 3XL ( largest snowflake warehouse)

Comment: why not open a support case at snowflake, still you should only start with 2  CTE and adding more and reduce the number of columns to a minmum, this looks more like a bug,

Comment: May be increase warehouse size and re-try ? like use LARGE /X-LARGE?